# Is it within ARIA / ADA guideline when an element or modal dialog is focused, it does not have a blue outline?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

For example, when a modal dialog is opened up, there can be irregular blue highlight around the modal dialog. For accessibility, it may be good, but while it helps 5% of users, to the other 95% of users, they will see the irregular and a bit obtrusive blue outline.

Does it comply with ARIA / ADA guideline to make the blue outline disappear for the general users, while let the accessibility browsers / readers force a blue outline? (by the rule of the browser's enforced CSS).

Answer (score 2):

This is defined in [WCAG 2.4.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible.html).

> 2.4.7 Focus Visible: Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible. (Level AA)

The focus indicator does not provide much benefit to screenreader users which often already benefit from improved visual and keyboard focus (assuming they can see)

People with low vision may use standard browsers without any other assistive technology and want to know where the keyboard focus is currently set. The keyboard focus is also useful for people with motor deficiency

But, there's nothing that says in accessibility guidelines that when you open a modal dialog, you should focus the whole dialog. You can perfectly focus the first interactive element (button or link) and make it the first element in the dialog.

Note that talking about accessibility, you are not helping 5% of people but according to WHO from 15% to 20%.

You can also perfectly, without removing the outline, make it more subtle.

Comment: there is one preferred recommendation that says focus on the whole modal dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467777 and I also remember some time ago, when the Apple Online Store website was so nicely designed, the blue outlined modal popped up, and it wasn't looking so good. By the way, I wonder for the general users, whether it could make sense for them to be able to go to the Settings to disable Accessibility features. Although it can make sense for people who needs it to enable it (default off), but maybe it is harder for them to enable it

Comment: @太極者無極而生: The linked answer also says that, in that case (focussing the whole modal), the `outline` should be set to `none`. Assuming that the modal is the only thing that can be seen/interacted with, I think this makes sense.